# Continuar paginación con el número 2 en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, paginación

Estoy utilizando codeigniter 3, estoy utilizando la clase [Pagination](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html) propia de codeigniter y tengo la siguiente función que recibe la url del sitio, el número de items a mostrar en la pagina y el total de items en general:

```
private function paginacion($url, $per_page, $total)
{
    $config = [
        'base_url'        => site_url($url),
        'per_page'        => 1,         
        'num_links'       => 5,
        'total_rows'      => $total/$per_page,
        'full_tag_open'   => "<ul class='pagination'>",
        'full_tag_close'  => "</ul>",
        'first_link'      => "Primero",
        'first_tag_open'  => '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_link'       => 'Último',
        'last_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'last_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'next_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'next_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'prev_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open'    => '<li>',
        'num_tag_close'   => '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open'    => "<li class='active'><a>",
        'cur_tag_close'   => '</a></li>',
    ];

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    return $this->pagination->create_links();
}
```

El problema es que al cargar la paginación en mi pagina al entrar al item 2 de la paginación, la url de mi sitio me dirige a prefijo número 1, el item 2 al prefijo 3 etc...

por ejemplo:
[image: paginacion]

#### ¿Es posible cambiar el prefijo en la url de acuerdo a la numeración de la paginación?

> 1 con 1, 2 con el 2...